# Combining two rows in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column called Side, that in the sample below takes the value E or W. I would like to combine the two rows into a single one. What has to happen is this: Parking_Spaces  Total_Vehicle_Count columns must be a sum of the two rows, the side column must be deleted, and the row count must be half what it was before.

Is there an easy approach for this?

```
Elmntkey    Study_Area  Sub_Area    Side    Unitdesc Parking_Category   Parking_Spaces  Total_Vehicle_Count Dp_Count    Construction    Event Closure   Subarea Label   Peak Hour? (Yes or No)  Day Time stamp                                                      
2014-04-08 08:00:00 24558   12th Ave - Weekday  unknown E   12TH AVE BETWEEN E MARION ST AND E SPRING ST    Paid Parking    8.0 1.0 0   No  No  12th Ave - Weekday  No  Weekday
2014-04-08 08:00:00 24557   12th Ave - Weekday  unknown W   12TH AVE BETWEEN E MARION ST AND E SPRING ST    Paid Parking    11.0    6.0 1   No  No  12th Ave - Weekday  No  Weekday
2014-04-08 09:00:00 24557   12th Ave - Weekday  unknown W   12TH AVE BETWEEN E MARION ST AND E SPRING ST    Paid Parking    11.0    6.0 1   No  No  12th Ave - Weekday  No  Weekday
2014-04-08 09:00:00 24558   12th Ave - Weekday  unknown E   12TH AVE BETWEEN E MARION ST AND E SPRING ST    Paid Parking    8.0 1.0 0   No  No  12th Ave - Weekday  No  Weekday
2014-04-08 10:00:00 24557   12th Ave - Weekday  unknown W   12TH AVE BETWEEN E MARION ST AND E SPRING ST    Paid Parking    11.0    10.0    1   No  No  12th Ave - Weekday  No  Weekday
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [df.groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15/groupby.html)

```
df.groupby(['Elmntkey','Study_Area','Sub_Area',' Unitdesc','Dp_Count',' Construction',' Event Closure','Subarea Label','Peak Hour? (Yes or No)','Day Time stamp'])[['Parking_Spaces','Total_Vehicle_Count']].sum().reset_index()
```

Output

```
   Elmntkey          Study_Area Sub_Area                                      Unitdesc  Dp_Count  Construction  Event Closure       Subarea Label Peak Hour? (Yes or No) Day Time stamp Parking_Spaces  Total_Vehicle_Count
0     24557  12th Ave - Weekday  unknown  12TH AVE BETWEEN E MARION ST AND E SPRING ST         1            No             No  12th Ave - Weekday                     No        Weekday           33.0                 22.0
1     24558  12th Ave - Weekday  unknown  12TH AVE BETWEEN E MARION ST AND E SPRING ST         0            No             No  12th Ave - Weekday                     No        Weekday           16.0                  2.0
```

Comment: This is not exactly what i want to do.I would like to combine the two rows, observed at 2014-04-08 08:00:00, giving a column which doesn't distinguish between east and west side of the street. As i have alot of different addresses in the dataset, the rows i want to combine is identical in all but elemntkey and side ( and of course the vehicle count/ parking spaces, which has to be summed together)

Comment: please add an expected output to your question

Answer (score 0):

Based on Shijos answer i solved this, with the following code:

```
#Getting the information
temp = df['raw'].groupby(['Time_Stamp','Unitdesc',], as_index=False)['Parking_Spaces','Total_Vehicle_Count'].sum()

#setting Time_Stamp as index and sort by the index, to match the target dataframe
temp = temp.set_index('Time_Stamp')
temp.sort_index(inplace=True)

# save the result to the target dataframe
df['droped']['Free_Spots'] = temp['Parking_Spaces']
df['droped']['Used_Spots'] = temp['Total_Vehicle_Count']
```

Shijo has been given credit for providing the correct answer.